# translating "const float *" from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

How can I translate this C++ code snippet into C# ?

```
void fm_getAABB(..., const float *points, ...)
{    
   // ...
   const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *) points;
   //...    
   const float *p = (const float *) source;
   //...
}
```

I've already tried to use a [C++ to C# converter](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html), but it doesn't seem able to translate it either.

**EDIT:**
Here's the whole function:

```
void fm_getAABB(unsigned int vcount, const float *points, unsigned int pstride,
    float *bmin, float *bmax)
{
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *) points;

    bmin[0] = points[0];
    bmin[1] = points[1];
    bmin[2] = points[2];

    bmax[0] = points[0];
    bmax[1] = points[1];
    bmax[2] = points[2];

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < vcount; i++)
    {
        source+=pstride;
        const float *p = (const float *) source;

        if ( p[0] < bmin[0] ) bmin[0] = p[0];
        if ( p[1] < bmin[1] ) bmin[1] = p[1];
        if ( p[2] < bmin[2] ) bmin[2] = p[2];

        if ( p[0] > bmax[0] ) bmax[0] = p[0];
        if ( p[1] > bmax[1] ) bmax[1] = p[1];
        if ( p[2] > bmax[2] ) bmax[2] = p[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: C# does not use pointers.  You should rewrite it.

Comment: As usual, the solution consists of: gaining an understanding of both languages; gaining an understanding of the original code; using that understanding to write the desired code.

Comment: I have some basic knowledge of the C++ language, but in this specific case I'm completely lost.

Comment: @SLaks: Starting your comment with a blatant untruth detracts from otherwise good advice.

Comment: What kind of data structure are you really wanting to pass in?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Read: _should_ not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to translate this as-is, by using the unsafe mode of C#. C# is perfectly capable of running this code with small modifications. You need to remove the const modifier for example.

If you manage to produce a managed-only version that would be preferable of course. But it is not entirely clear that that is even possible: Your function is performing certain pointer manipulations which might lead to unaligned access. Managed arrays cannot pe accessed in an unaligned way using managed-only features.

Comment: How did you rewrite this function if you were me?

Comment: That depends: If you don't need a safe-code version I'd just keep the pointers. Less work, less potential for introduced bugs.

Comment: I'm trying to convert it using the unsafe keyword and I'm removing the "unsigned" keywords is that ok?

Comment: @EduardoBrites, you can remove the unsigned stuff (in this case). If you need a safe-code version, try to understand what the stride parameter *means* (semantically). Then, try to get rid of the cast to char*. As I don't understand what the function purpose is I cannot comment more concretely.

Comment: The function's purpose is to compute an axis aligned bounding box from an array of vertices. The pointer conversions exist for no other reason than that `pstride` is expressed in bytes, so to get from one vertex to the next requires that the address be incremented by `pstride` bytes. If `pstride` is guaranteed to be a multiple of `sizeof(float)` then the pointer conversions could be replaced with `points+=pstride/sizeof(float);` although converting the function to C# requires knowing how the interface will be converted.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a safe way to use pointers in C#, C# is a much safer language than C++ but this can also make it more restrictive in cases like this.

C++ will allow you to do many things other languages can't because it leaves the safety up to the programmer, C# however puts safety first and hence restricts things like this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without seeing more of the context. I expect you will be able to replace all the use of pointers with an array of floats.

Normally a C++ pointer is used for a single item or for an array of items, but I can't for sure tell which from your sample code - but the use of the plural "points" seems to indicate that it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

To convert between arrays of chars (bytes) and other values, use the BitConverter class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

That's C# answer to type punning
`const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *) points;`

But it requires deep understanding what this function does and basically reimplementing it in a C# way.